# If you're in the US on a long-term visa status (H1/L1 visa), do you need a new I-94 for every re-entry?

Tags: usa

Let's say you're in the US on a H1/L1 visa and your I-94 is valid for a year into the future. Now you take a flight to the UK and come back - would the immigration officer issue you a fresh I-94 or would the old one be reused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would be issued a new I-94. The I-94 is for each entry only and your status ceases when you leave the US.

The only exception where the I-94 matters for the next entry is if you re-enter the US with an expired visa (or without a visa of the right type if you changed status in the US) after a trip of less than 30 days to Canada or Mexico, where they will admit you on Automatic Revalidation until the expiration of your previous I-94. Also, if you are in the US on the Visa Waiver Program and re-enter after a trip to Canada, Mexico, or adjacent islands, you are not given a new duration of 90 days and you are admitted until the expiration of your previous I-94.

But since you are going to the UK, neither of these apply, and you will be admitted anew on the basis of your visa. You will be granted a new I-94.

Comment: +1, but I note that from postings here and on [Travel.SE], and from one incident traveling to Canada with a visa nonimmigrant before the electronic I-94 was introduced, it seems that CBP does (at least sometimes) apply automatic revalidation even in cases where the visa is not expired, reusing the prior I-94.  I also note that the reuse of the prior I-94 for VWP travelers is nominally at the discretion of the immigration officer, though it seems that it isn't applied this way in practice.  In short, it looks like the actual procedures have diverged somewhat from the letter of the law.